# Vue, spring boot, jpa environment. An error occurs on the client when uploading a file

Tags: vue.js, multipartfile

```
@PostMapping(value = "/admin/item/new", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public ItemNewResponse itemNew(@RequestParam(value = "itemImgFile") List<MultipartFile> files ) {
```

...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDRjS.png)

As a result of running Postman, there is no problem with the backend.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wryVG.png)

Front-End










...

```
 const formData = new FormData();  
  for(let i = 0; i < this.upload.length; i++) {
    formData.append('itemImgFile', this.upload[i])
  }

  axios.post("admin/item/new", formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
    withCredentials: true
  }).then(({data}) => {

    state.errorMessage = data.errorMessage;

    if (state.errorMessage != null) {
      alert(state.errorMessage);
    }
    ...
```

I don't know what's wrong with vue.

Comment: "_An error occurs_" ... what error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.